# "no module found: tkinter" after deploying in heroku

Tags: python, heroku, tkinter

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named '_tkinter'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://facerecogs.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 2.2.6
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named '_tkinter'
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py in <module>, line 36
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.10
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:32:02 +0000
```

Comment: In Py3 the module has been renamed to `tkinter`

Comment: welcome to SO. Edit your question to add more context as well as your code; What is the purpose of tkinter in a web app hosted/deployed on Heroku?

Comment: You're almost certainly not going to be able to run tkinter on heroku. Tkinter requires a display.

Answer (score 1):

Check your main urls.py if you import anything from turtle and remove it. Once I removed "from turtle import st", it worked for me.